# Geometry question.

Tags: geometry

[image]

Triangle ABC is an equilateral triangle. BC is drawn to D and BA is drawn to E. AE = BD. CE=a. What is DE in terms of CE?

I can't seem to create an auxiliary line that can help me to get the answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post a diagram of the problem.

Comment: how do you post a picture?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Click on edit, then click on the button that looks like a sun above a mountain range.

Comment: As far as I can tell, $DE=CE$

Comment: How? They are not necessarily the same.

Comment: My diagram is not drawn to scale.

Comment: Try using law or cosines.  I haven't worked out the details but I think it might work.

Comment: Empirically, I think they are the same.  I cannot prove it - otherwise I would answer

Comment: I just used law of cosines, and it seems to be equal.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a diagram that should help you... Just draw parallelogram $BDFA$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following figure.

[image]

Now, apply the rule of cosines for the triangle $BCE$.

$$a^2=(2c+d)^2+c^2-2(2c+d)c\cos(60^{\circ})=3c^2+3cd+d^2.$$
Then apply the same for the triangle $BDE$.

$$x^2=(2c+d)^2+(c+d)^2-2(2c+d)(c+d)\cos(60^{\circ})=3c^2+3cd+d^2.$$

That is, $a=x$.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the law of cosines twice (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yivf.jpg)